# How To Display Query Result From Entered Value of Input Field To Another Input Field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input

Basicly I want to enter a value into input field. And based on that value, I want do query sql and display its value into another field (without refresh page).

HTML

```
<input name="idno[]" type="text" /><select name="curr[]"><option value=""></option></select><input name="amount[]" type="text" />
<input name="idno[]" type="text" /><select name="curr[]"><option value=""></option></select><input name="amount[]" type="text" />
```

So, when I enter value into input field (name idno[]) then input field (name curr[] and amount[] will display query result ex: select * from table where id = 'idno'

Please help me guys..

**EDIT**

This is my code running for static input field..

```
<form name="myForm">
<table width="50%" border="1">
<tr>
<td><input type="text"
onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);" name="username" /></td>
<td>
<div id="displayDiv">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="curr"></td><td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(str)
{
    var httpxml;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
    try
    {
        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
function stateChanged()
{
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
    }
}
var url="cek.php";
url=url+"?txt="+str;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Could you give me solution so it can be working for dynamic input field (i mean working for add new input field, etc)

Thanks

Comment: where's the rest of your code? a big chunk of JS/jQuery and PHP are missing

Comment: Basicly i'm still confuse how to get value of of input field name idno[] and how to display its query result (i can do this in php) to input field name amount[] and cur[]

Comment: You need AJAX. I also don't know why you have select multiples without `<select name='curr[]' multiple='multiple'>`. You should only have one name, as well, with the exception of radio buttons, and checkbox multiples. With a select multiple your user just has the option of selecting multiple items with `ctrl+click` or `click+shift+click`.

Comment: Maybe you can call me lazy,, but i'm really blank.. could you give another sample code PHPglue... many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by good old html with a submit button and a form which submits the values to a php script which is returning the form with updated values. But if you want it a little bit more 'cool' you need to use javaScript to listen for change-events on the input to fire ajax requests to a php script and receiving the query result for displaying it back on the html site. The keywords to search for are event listeners and ajax. There are tons of tutorials for how to do that in the www.

Comment: Without page refresh.

Comment: the truth is i already searching for doing this and i found it use ajax and jquery.. but like i said i'm stil blank how to do this... i know the scenario but doesn't know to implement it.. the scenario is get value from entered input field name idno[] and then do query in php to select curr and amount based on idno (i can do this query in php) and finally display it in input field name curr[] and amount[]... wish there will be someone help me.. kindly regards

Answer (score 0):

**Points you should remember :**

1) Don't use key up instead use change or input it is far better

2) For  a live search where the results are appended or added your are going to need following

things

a) html

b) jquery

c) sql

Take the following example of searching people

**JQUERY**

```
    var name;

    $("body").on("input","#search_box_input",function(){
        name = $("#search_box_input").val();
        if(name !="")
        {
        $.post("../PHP/search_people.php",{name:name},function(returned_name)
        {
            $("#all_names_div").html(returned_name).fadeIn("slow");

        }); 
        }
    });
```

**Your PHP and SQL query should be like this :**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

`$result = mysql_query("select * from people where name like '%$name%'");`

`while ($returned_name = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo $returned_name['name'];
}`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'am create a new post to post my code. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544843/show-query-result-into-input-field-based-on-user-input-value-in-dynamic-input-fi please help me masta..